# Why my MDIChild forms not open in wsMaximized state every time?

Tags: delphi, vcl, mdichild

Delphi MDIChild windowState problem

I have a delphi project with a MDI and childs. When I created a new child form, this occupies perfctly a reserved space on main form (child wsMaximized).

But when a create another child form (without closed first child), the first child "lost a wsMaximized state".

Resume: I need the child forms maximized every time, but when second child is opened, the "windowstate" another childs is changed.

First child:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.PosicionarForm(AForm: TForm);
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  GetWindowRect(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, Rect);

  InflateRect(Rect, -2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER),
    -2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER));
  OffsetRect(Rect, -Rect.Left, -Rect.Top);

  AForm.BoundsRect := Rect;
end;

procedure TfrmPrincipal.actCadastroFornecedorExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
    frmCadastroFornecedor := TfrmCadastroFornecedor.Create(Application);
    PosicionarForm(frmCadastroFornecedor);
    frmCadastroFornecedor.Show;
  svSub.Visible := False;
  SV.Opened := False;
end;
```

[image]

Secound child:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.actCadastroProdutosExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmCadastroProduto := TfrmCadastroProduto.Create(Application);
  PosicionarForm(frmCadastroProduto);

  frmCadastroProduto.Show;

  svSub.Visible := False;
  SV.Opened := False;
end;
```

[image]

EDIT:

I created a new project, have 3 forms. The code is very simple, but this behavior continues.

Main FORM:

```
 unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    screen11: TMenuItem;
    screen21: TMenuItem;
    procedure screen11Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure screen21Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
unit2, unit3;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.screen11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form2 := tform2.Create(Application);
  form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.screen21Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
form3 := tform3.Create(Application);
  form3.Show;
end;

end.
```

Child 1:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

Child 2:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I edited my question, thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I created a new project, have 3 forms. The code is very simple, but this behavior continues, when I close the secound child, the first is not "wsmaximized" anymore. See my question in "EDIT"

Comment: I can not reproduce what you claim, with the code you have provided. I had to do following, which you did not mention, in order to make a proper MDI test project: 1) remove creation of forms `Form2` and `Form3` from the `.dpr` 2) set `Form1.FormStyle = fsMDIForm` and `Form2` and `Form3` `FormStyle = fsMDIChild` 3) set `Form2` and `Form3` `WindowState = wsMaximized`. Running and clicking `screen1` and `screen2` creates the two child form maximised. Destroying the topmost child (`Form3`) with the small `X` button in the main form deletes `Form3` and `Form2`becomes visible, maximized. Win10, XE7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error (once again an example of how important a **complete**, minimal, reproducible, example is) I was able to reproduce the error you ask about. If you had included the the `.dfm` files, the actual problem had been clear much sooner.

Now, to the problem that the `WindowState` of the forms change from `wsMaximized` to `wsNormal`  after deletion of one of the childforms.

This happens when you have removed `biMaximise` from `BorderIcons` for forms `Form2` and `Form3`

Cure: Let `BorderIcons.biMaximise` be selected.

I also suggest you remove `PosicionarForm(AForm: TForm);` from the main form. It doesn't appear to do anything useful.